# nav-menu not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a nav-menu icon I want to show it only on small screen(less than 768px).
Here is the code

```css
@media screen and(max-width:768px){
  .nav-menu{display:block;}
}
.nav-menu{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu" id="nav"><h3>&#9776;</h3></div>
```

However it is not visible in small screen.What is wrong with my code.Thanks in advance.
**UPDATE:**
Here the [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a56chhej/)

Comment: Try putting the `display: none;` before the `@media`... looks like you're overwriting the @media rule

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 yups i am using bootstrap however it is not working in simple js fiddle without bootstrap too.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter You should write that as an answer.  This is clearly a cascade order issue.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter still not working

Comment: @Anonymous Create a fiddle to reproduce the problem please

Comment: @Anonymous It's probably still not working because `and(max-width:768px)` is a syntax error breaking your media query.  Try `and (max-width:768px)` (notice the extra space).

Comment: @JosephMarikle still not working you can try in my fiddle link

Comment: @Anonymous It works.  With the order reversed and the syntax error removed, it behaves as expected.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/8cyoL3mz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally
 i got answer there were silly mistakes:

```css
.nav-menu{
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .nav-menu{display:block;}
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu" id="nav"><h3>&#9776;</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn those rules around, otherwise the second one will overwrite the first:

```
.nav-menu{
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .nav-menu{display:block;}
}
```

Comment: what error? Did you try to add a space between "and" and "(max-width..."?

Comment: "and(max-width:768px)" will create error.It should be "and (max-width:768px)".Please edit it

Comment: that's what i wrote in my comment. Anyway, I edited it in my answer now.